# Application Form Validation using OpenCV

Tags: java, c#, opencv

The task is to validate the application forms which were being scanned.
The forms must be validate against the template form to detect whether they are dirty, different or not scanning properly(rotated or only being scan halves).

I'm using template matching currently and using the max value as the threshold to validate them. Are there any other good alternated solutions to validate them. Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: Very hard to tell without examples. There are good methods to find the orientation of text/rotation, and also to find the text areas in a document. Search google from "image segmentation for document recognition".

Comment: You can compare documents in the form of images using openCV. However, it would be good if you can explain your problem

Answer (score 2):

may you want to have a look here [Contour Analysis for Image Recognition in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C)
Basically this approach lets you compare descriptors of shapes. It is very powerful and fast, takes different rotations or scales into acount, but you will get into serious trouble if the scan is malformed.

Comment: I'm thinking about background differencing with threshold as well. I might need to segment the image using submat though. But still I can't differentiate well written answer sheets and dirty answer sheets.

Comment: could you add an example, a screenshot for instance?